# Getting touch event when the user taps exactly 5 times

Tags: android, xamarin.android, touch

I would like to show a dialog (secret menu) when a user taps 5 times anywhere in the activity. Is this somehow possible? I wasn't able to achieve this and also haven't found anything in the documentation.

Comment: Check my answer too, Is that what you want??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code: overwrite the `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)` method in your activity and count number of taps..

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private int count = 0;

//detect any touch event in the screen

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {  

    int eventaction = event.getAction();
     if (eventaction == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

     //get system current milliseconds
     long time= System.currentTimeMillis();
     ++count;

     if (count==5) {
        //show Dialog
        new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
              .setTitle("Your Alert")
              .setMessage("Your Message")
              .setCancelable(false)
              .setPositiveButton("ok", new OnClickListener() {
                  @Override
                  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                      // Whatever...
                  }
              }).show();

     }
     return true;    
    }
    return false;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First Intialize global variable **mCounter** which keep track how many time you click on activity.

int mCounter = 0;

you can override onTouchEvent method like below inside activity

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                // increase counter here
                counter = counter + 1;
                if(counter == 5) {
                  // show dialog here
               }
                break;


        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Hope these help you.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty easy. The code will go like this :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private int count = 0;

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {  

int eventaction = event.getAction();
if (eventaction == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
count++;
}
else{
break;
}
if (count==5) {
    //do whatever you need
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You tapped 5 times on screen",
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }
 return true;    
}
return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**For your information**

Yes you can override `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)`

**But**

> User get the secret menu whenever he complete the 5 touches.
>
> But for a real **Secret Menu**,When ever the user touches 5 times
>   **Quickly** the dialogue shows up.

For that

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private final int count = 0;
Handler handler;
Runnable runnable;


@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    int eventaction = event.getAction();
    if (eventaction == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

        count++;
        if (count > 0) {
            handler = new Handler();
            runnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    count = 0;
                }
            };
            handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);  // clear counter if user does not touch for one sec
        }
        if (count == 5) {
            //do whatever

        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

If the user does not touch for a moment make the counter to 0.

> Be careful to import right handler
>
> ```
> import android.os.Handler;
> ```